# Query to return at the least 1 record per ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a solution to this example. Each ID may have multiple records, some including just NULL under "hobby", others with the name of a hobby, or some with both NULL and a hobby name. I wish to return rows with these 3 outcomes:

- If this ID has only NULL under "hobby", return 1 row
- If this ID is populated under "hobby", return all populated rows
- If this ID has a mix of NULL and populated under "hobby", return only populated rows

To gain a visual of what I am trying to achieve:

| ID | Name | Hobby |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | NULL |
| 1 | Alex | Soccer |
| 1 | Alex | Skiing |
| 2 | Roger | NULL |
| 2 | Roger | NULL |
| 3 | Jason | Hockey |
| 3 | Jason | Lacrosse |

Return:

| ID | Name | Hobby |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Soccer |
| 1 | Alex | Skiing |
| 2 | Roger | NULL |
| 3 | Jason | Hockey |
| 3 | Jason | Lacrosse |

Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

I have only tried using SELECT DISTINCT but quickly realized this would include 1 NULL row with other populated rows with the same ID. I am new enough to SQL I have not thoroughly learned all the syntax.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You've tagged 2008 *and* 2012 here, are you *really* using both? *Both are also *completely* unsupported, so you *need* for get that finalised upgrade plan implemented ASAP.

Comment: The reason you are struggling here is because your table design is not properly normalized.

Comment: @DaleK It has been added to the post, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @SamBaker are any of the answers helpful to you? You've had a bunch of people spent time on your issue, the least you can do is provide feedback as to whether the solutions work for you.

Comment: @DaleK I have not been able to find a solution to my problem yet, and yes sorry for the wait, I did not have access to my database and am going to create a new question with a MRE and my full query.

Comment: Then please comment against each answer explaining how it doesn't answer your question so that people can impove their answer. Alternatively, since I think they may answer the question as asked, you should accept one before asking a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Since you only want to keep nulls where there aren't any other values, if you sort and number them so that nulls are last on the list, you'd only want to keep a single null that appears in the #1 spot.

As SQL Server doesn't yet have the option to specify null sort order you have to bucket them with a `case` expression. After the ranking you'll then keep anything that isn't null and any value that rose to the top regardless of what it is:

```
with "data" as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by ID
            order by case when Hobby is not null then 0 else 1 end) as rn
    from T
)
select ID, "Name", Hobby
from "data"
where Hobby is not null or rn = 1;
```

Comment: @Dale, I do prefer quotes to be semi-portable but I was just confirming that "data" is not a reserved word. Why do you prefer to be quoted?

Comment: DB2 and Teradata have it as reserved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Comment: Really should include a description of why and how this works ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have here, as pointed out by others, is your database is not normalized correctly, so you have to go through a lot of gymnastics to get what you want. What you should really have is a table of people, a table of hobbies, and a table mapping them together. From there, it's a simple left join between the person and the table mapping the two together.

I will show you a solution to your table as described right now, but first I want to show you how I would set up your schema (also, my solution to your problem basically *fakes* the schema I'm about to describe).

First, let's create the basic tables: `#Person`, `#Hobby` and the mapping table `#PersonHobby`

```
drop table if exists #Person
create table #Person
(
    PersonId int primary key,
    Name varchar(50)
)

drop table if exists #Hobby
create table #Hobby
(
    HobbyId int primary key,
    Hobby varchar(50)
)

drop table if exists #PersonHobby
create table #PersonHobby
(
    PersonId int,
    HobbyId int
    primary key clustered (PersonId, HobbyId)
)
```

Now I'll populate the tables with your data. `Person` and `Hobby` are just the distinct values from your example data (note, I added a `HobbyId` field to `#Hobby` because I wouldn't recommend having the `Hobby` be the primary key. There are arguments that it could be, but to suggest general best practices, I'm going to create a surrogate key here).

```
insert into #Person
(
    PersonId,
    Name
)
values
    (1, 'Alex'),
    (2, 'Roger'),
    (3, 'Jason')

insert into #Hobby
(
    HobbyId,
    Hobby
)
values
    (1, 'Soccer'),
    (2, 'Skiing'),
    (3, 'Hockey'),
    (4, 'Lacrosse')
```

Finally, populate the mappings. You can do this by any means you like; I did it by creating a `CTE` which has the human-readable names and then looking up the surrogate ids, but you do you here.

```
;with personHobbies (PersonName, Hobby) as
(
    select 'Alex', 'Soccer' union all
    select 'Alex', 'Skiing' union all
    select 'Jason', 'Hockey' union all
    select 'Jason', 'Lacrosse'
)
insert into #PersonHobby
(
    PersonId,
    HobbyId
)
select
    p.PersonId,
    h.HobbyId
from personHobbies ph
inner join #Person p
    on ph.PersonName = p.name
inner join #Hobby h
    on ph.Hobby = h.Hobby
```

Now select out your data with a simple `left outer join` (and another join to look up the `Hobby` from the `HobbyId`)

```
select 
    p.PersonId,
    p.name,
    h.hobby
from #Person p
left outer join #PersonHobby ph
    on p.PersonId = ph.PersonId
left outer join #Hobby h
    on ph.HobbyId = h.HobbyId
```

In a nutshell, that is how I would set up your tables. Now; if for some reason you cannot alter your schema, you can *fake* all that by creating `CTEs` that look like `#Person` and `#PersonHobby`

```
-- Solution with your schema
;with data as
(
    select Id, Name, Hobby
    from
    (
        values
            (1, 'Alex', null),
            (1, 'Alex', 'Soccer'),
            (1, 'Alex', 'Skiing'),
            (2, 'Roger', null),
            (2, 'Roger', null),
            (3, 'Jason', 'Hockey'),
            (3, 'Jason', 'Lacrosse')
    ) a (Id, Name, Hobby)

), people as
(
    select distinct Id, Name
    from data
), personHobbies as
(
    select distinct Id, Hobby
    from data
    where Hobby is not null
)
select 
    p.Id, p.Name, ph.Hobby
from people p
left outer join personHobbies ph
    on p.Id = ph.Id
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/igH1ggPQ) with the full example

Comment: Why not follow best practice by semi-colon terminating your statements? Instead of adding them before CTEs only?

Comment: I wish I could try this, but I do not have permissions in my database to create, update, and alter tables.  This example is based off a query I have created that spans 4 tables within this database. I'm sorry if this may have been wasted time.

Comment: Not at all. Just wanted to share the thoughts with you. Also, I do have a solution at the end of my post which works with the data you have.

Comment: @SamBaker then your question may be an XY Problem... If you open another question showing the 4 tables and your query, it's very possible we can adapt it for you to generate the correct results (instead of fixing them after they've already gone wrong).

Comment: @MatBailie I could possibly do that, but I cannot disclose information on these tables, most likely only column names. If you think that may hinder a solution to this problem let me know, and if not I will try to prepare a question with all the information I am able to give.

Comment: @SamBaker You can make a [mre] of literally *any* model without divulging commercially sensitive information. I do recommend doing so, you will very likely learn a better option than just fixing the symptoms of an underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Exclude rows where hobby is null but a non null hobby exists
2. Group by to combine similar rows (or just use `distinct`)

```
-- Prepare example sample data
declare @MyTable table (ID int, [Name] varchar(12), Hobby varchar(12));

insert into @MyTable
  select *
  from (
    values
    (1, 'Alex',  NULL),
    (1, 'Alex',  'Soccer'),
    (1, 'Alex',  'Skiing'),
    (2, 'Roger', NULL),
    (2, 'Roger', NULL),
    (3, 'Jason', 'Hockey'),
    (3, 'Jason', 'Lacrosse')
  ) x (ID, [Name], Hobby);

-- Solution
select ID, [Name], Hobby
from @MyTable t1
where not exists (
  select 1
  from @MyTable t2
  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.[Name] = t1.[Name] and t1.Hobby is null and t2.Hobby is not null
)
group by ID, [Name], Hobby;
```

Returns as desired:

| ID | Name | Hobby |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Skiing |
| 1 | Alex | Soccer |
| 2 | Roger | NULL |
| 3 | Jason | Hockey |
| 3 | Jason | Lacrosse |

Note: Please provide us with DDL+DML in future (as shown above)

Comment: Will do in the future, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

One more technique.

**Example Data**

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') is not null)
    DROP TABLE #tmp;

CREATE TABLE #tmp ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(12), [Hobby] varchar(12));

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES
    (1, 'Alex', NULL),
    (1, 'Alex', 'Soccer'),
    (1, 'Alex', 'Skiing'),
    (2, 'Roger', NULL),
    (2, 'Roger', NULL),
    (3, 'Jason', 'Hockey'),
    (3, 'Jason', 'Hockey'), -- << added double
    (3, 'Jason', 'Lacrosse');
```

**Main Query**

```
select 
    x.[ID],
    x.[Name],
    h.[Hobby]
from (
    SELECT  
        [ID], [Name]
    FROM #tmp
    GROUP BY [ID], [Name]
) x
LEFT JOIN #tmp h on h.[ID] = x.[ID] AND h.Hobby is not null
--GROUP BY x.[ID], x.[Name], h.[Hobby]
```

**Logic:** The from sub-query uses group by to get the distinct id’s and name’s. This gives you 1 entry for all the ids and names. Then the left join grabs all hobbies where it is not null. If there is no match, you get the required 1 null.

If someone has duplicate hobbies, the hobby would repeat – not sure if you wanted that or not. Uncomment the group by if not.

**Results:**

| ID | Name | Hobby |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Soccer |
| 1 | Alex | Skiing |
| 2 | Roger | NULL |
| 3 | Jason | Hockey |
| 3 | Jason | **Hockey** |
| 3 | Jason | Lacrosse |