# Query to return at the least 1 record per ID Part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a question earlier to this problem and none have seem to work for my case. To recap, I need to return 1 or more entries per NOTRID:
-If a NOTRID has only blank string entries under QualitativeResult, return only 1 entry
-If a NOTRID has a mix of blank and populated entries under QualitativeResult, return only populated results

In my case, NOTRIDs will have at the least a blank entry.

Below, I have tried to give all information needed to assist me. Using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

*Query:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.NotrId AS NOTR
    ,c.DateCompleted AS Month
    ,c.ClientName AS Client
    ,c.SupplierName AS Supplier
    ,c.FacilityName AS Facility
    ,d.ParameterNumber AS PN
    ,d.Name AS [Parameter Name]
    ,a.QualitativeResult AS Performance
    ,a.Passed
    ,a.ParameterId
FROM dbo.Results AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Id
        ,NotrId
    FROM dbo.NotrResult
) AS b
    ON a.NotrResultId = b.Id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        ClientName
        ,NotrId
        ,SupplierName
        ,FacilityName
        ,ProductLineName
        ,Qualification
        ,DateCompleted
    FROM dbo.vNOTR
    WHERE DateCompleted IS NOT NULL
) as c
    ON b.NotrId = c.NotrId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Id
        ,Name
        ,ParameterNumber
        ,Repeated
    FROM dbo.Parameter
) AS d
    ON a.ParameterId = d.Id
WHERE c.ClientName LIKE ('Sb')
AND d.ParameterNumber IN('5006')
AND c.ProductLineName LIKE ('%12%')
AND c.ProductLineName NOT LIKE ('%Lid%')
AND c.Qualification = ''
ORDER BY PN
```

*Results:*

| NOTR | Month | Client | Supplier | Facility | PN | Parameter Name | Performance | Passed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-14 13:30:00.000 | Sb | Pl | St | 5006 | 45t |  | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-12-14 13:35:00.000 | Sb | Pl | Dt | 5006 | 45t |  | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-12-14 13:35:00.000 | Sb | Pl | Dt | 5006 | 45t | 1/15 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 5006 | 45t |  | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 5006 | 45t |  | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 5006 | 45t | 6/15 | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-12-14 13:45:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Ds | 5006 | 45t |  | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-12-14 13:45:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Ds | 5006 | 45t | 1/15 | 0 |

*Desired Return:*

| NOTR | Month | Client | Supplier | Facility | PN | Parameter Name | Performance | Passed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-14 13:30:00.000 | Sb | Pl | St | 5006 | 45t |  | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-12-14 13:35:00.000 | Sb | Pl | Dt | 5006 | 45t | 1/15 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 5006 | 45t | 6/15 | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-12-14 13:45:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Ds | 5006 | 45t | 1/15 | 0 |

*Table: Results*

| ParameterId | QualitativeResult | Passed | NotrResultId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD0EEEFC-A2F9-447C-A9B6-4931C83D8EAC |  | 1 | 32945339-3D85-406F-8B6D-438199A0DA9E |
| CD0EEEFC-A2F9-447C-A9B6-4931C83D8EAC |  | 1 | 68C91962-1B43-4F26-AB78-40BA062B6319 |
| CD0EEEFC-A2F9-447C-A9B6-4931C83D8EAC | 1/15 | 0 | 68C91962-1B43-4F26-AB78-40BA062B6319 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 |  | 0 | C83B6EF5-0004-4D6D-BD9A-6338407D3086 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 |  | 1 | C83B6EF5-0004-4D6D-BD9A-6338407D3086 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 | 6/15 | 0 | C83B6EF5-0004-4D6D-BD9A-6338407D3086 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 |  | 1 | 8C5F48C6-A2FB-419C-A318-032D97AE8F45 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 | 1/15 | 0 | 8C5F48C6-A2FB-419C-A318-032D97AE8F45 |

*Table: NotrResult*

| Id | NotrId |
| --- | --- |
| 32945339-3D85-406F-8B6D-438199A0DA9E | 1 |
| 68C91962-1B43-4F26-AB78-40BA062B6319 | 2 |
| 68C91962-1B43-4F26-AB78-40BA062B6319 | 2 |
| C83B6EF5-0004-4D6D-BD9A-6338407D3086 | 3 |
| C83B6EF5-0004-4D6D-BD9A-6338407D3086 | 3 |
| C83B6EF5-0004-4D6D-BD9A-6338407D3086 | 3 |
| 8C5F48C6-A2FB-419C-A318-032D97AE8F45 | 4 |
| 8C5F48C6-A2FB-419C-A318-032D97AE8F45 | 4 |

*View: vNOTR*

| NotrId | ClientName | SupplierName | FacilityName | ProductLineName | Qualification | DateCompleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sb | Pl | St | 12oz |  | 2021-12-14 13:30:00.000 |
| 2 | Sb | Pl | Dt | 12oz |  | 2021-12-14 13:35:00.000 |
| 2 | Sb | Pl | Dt | 12oz |  | 2021-12-14 13:35:00.000 |
| 3 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 12oz |  | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 |
| 3 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 12oz |  | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 |
| 3 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 12oz |  | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 |
| 4 | Sb | Dc | Ds | 12oz |  | 2021-12-14 13:45:00.000 |
| 4 | Sb | Dc | Ds | 12oz |  | 2021-12-14 13:45:00.000 |

*Table: Parameter*

| Id | Name | ParameterNumber | Repeated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD0EEEFC-A2F9-447C-A9B6-4931C83D8EAC | 45t | 5006 | 15 |
| CD0EEEFC-A2F9-447C-A9B6-4931C83D8EAC | 45t | 5006 | 15 |
| CD0EEEFC-A2F9-447C-A9B6-4931C83D8EAC | 45t | 5006 | 15 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 | 45t | 5006 | 15 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 | 45t | 5006 | 15 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 | 45t | 5006 | 15 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 | 45t | 5006 | 15 |
| BA8DDBA0-71B0-4B7E-9B40-CAC20439EF96 | 45t | 5006 | 15 |

I have tried answers that were given from my last question ([Query to return at the least 1 record per ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802976/query-to-return-at-the-least-1-record-per-id)) but none seem to work for me. I do not have permissions to create tables for myself so I took the data from the tables provided to me and condensed to what information I think would be required for this question.

Comment: It looks like you want the first matching NOTRID record if they all passed and the last matching notrid record if any failed.  Is that correct?

Comment: @BartMcEndree I would like to: If a NOTRID has only NULL entries under QualitativeResult, return 1 NULL entry. If a NOTRID has a mix of NULL and populated entries, return all populated entries. In my case, each NOTRID should have at the least a NULL entry. Sorry I should have included this in the explanation.

Comment: @SamBaker What doesn't work about shawnt00's answer to your first question? That seems spot on and clean. Could you describe how that result differs from what you want to see?

Comment: Thank you for including so much detail in your question. For future reference though, questions stand a higher chance of being answered if you can reduce it down to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I get the feeling a lot of the code you've included is immaterial to your question and only serves to obfuscate the fields and tables that are actually relevant. For anyone taking a stab at this, here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WOj1irN3) with the provided data loaded into temp tables.

Comment: Do you have actual *null* values in the  `QualitativeResult` column or empty strings? (They are not the same.)

Comment: @TN I did not know there was a difference, the QualitativeResult column only has empty strings, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Xedni Yes sorry for including the irrelevant material. I currently do not have access to the database but needed to get this question out. I did not want to remove anything with the possibility of it creating errors for people since I could not check and confirm the query would still operate.

Comment: @Error_2646 I believe with shawnt00's answer it would return a blank table for me. I tried to see if I could find where the query went wrong but I had no luck, it still executed but returned no populated rows.

Comment: Your data appears incomplete. Your query references the `NotrId` column in `vNOTR`, but your data shows no such column. See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n3R9LgTj). I believe the corrected data should be something like [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u4xNg1II), where I added the `NotrId` column, copied the values (in order) from the `NotrResult` table and then eliminated the apparent duplicate rows from `NotrResult`. Does this look correct?

Comment: @TN Yes that looks correct, sorry for that, I am not sure why that was excluded.

Comment: So the first thing that is a red flag for me is seeing a query that starts with `SELECT DISTINCT`. This usually means a problem with under-constrained joins or multiple independent one-to-many joins. However, in this case, you have duplicate rows in several or your sample data tables. `NotrResult` had 8 rows, 4 duplicates. `vNOTR` has 8 rows with 4 duplicates. `Parameter` has 8 frows with 6 duplicates. Does your source data really look like this? (Or did you perhaps cut and paste columns from the results of a "select * from x join y join z" like query, not realizing you were copying dups?)

Comment: I agree. Whenever a query starts with `SELECT DISTINCT` it is very likely the query is inappropriate. The first thing to ask yourself is then: Why is `DISTINCT` necessary? Is the query unnecessarily producing the duplicates itself? (Maybe it's even worse, though: it's not your query but an inappropriate data model.) As to the rest of the query: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, notrid FROM dbo.notrresult) AS b ON ...` is just `LEFT JOIN dbo.notrresult AS b ON ...`. Don't make the query more complicated than need be...

Comment: Then you are outer joning tables - or you think you are. But the `WHERE` clause renders these joins mere inner joins, because in an outer joined row, the columns of the outer joined table are all null. `WHERE c.ClientName = 'Sb'` is dismissing all outer joined c rows for instance.

Comment: On your previous question you didn't give any of the answerers any feedback as to why the queries didn't work - which you should do do that they have a chance to improve them

Comment: You should also consider accepting one of the answers, because I am fairly sure they answer the question as asked.

Comment: As a side note, I suggest that you get into the habit of using meaningful mnemonic table aliases instead of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.  For example, `Result AS r`, `NotrResult AS nr`, `vNOTR AS vn`, and `Parameter AS p` (or whatever makes more sense in your environment). This would make it easier for someone else reading your query to follow the logic - whether today or several years down the road.

Comment: @TN and everyone else thank you for your help and expertise. There is still much for me to learn, like something as simple as not needing to call out specific columns for joins which I was shown how to use.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  I'm not sure if our data model is appropriate considering I am this companies start to data analytics, and need to educate myself on what would be appropriate.

Comment: @DaleK I wanted to create a question that I thought represented my problem more accurately and believed my application of those answers were not being executed correctly with my capability.

Comment: @SamBaker you should still accept an answer to your previous question because people spent time on it and did provide an answer to the question asked

Comment: My data model? I didn't mention any data model. I just mentioned flaws in your query and that you should think about why you need `DISTINCT`, which is really a rare thing to do and most often just an indicator that the joins are leading to undesired duplicates. I see you took the easy route and just cleaned up afterwards (by accepting T N's solution. It is not a bad solution, but you should strive to write appropriate queries in the first place, rather then to muddle through with a late clean-up. On large tables those intermediate duplicates can cause big problems with a query.

Comment: Then, T N asked you why there are duplicates in the tables shown. You haven't answered. Are these mere copy & paste mistakes? Or do the tables really contain duplicates. If so, why? What would it mean if a row existed twice in a table? I am getting the impression that you don't want to think too much about your data and the proper way to write a query, but this is what you *should* do. And Dale K is right: you asked a question and got answers that solve the problem you described, so accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the logic from [shawnt00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802976/77803104#77803104) to your previous question. The main difference is that you dealing with *empty* values instead of *null* values.

1. Wrap your existing query up in a CTE (common table expression) or subquery.
2. Add *window* `ROW_NUMBER()` function to number the results per `NotrId`, placing any non-empty values first.
3. Add logic to the outer query to include the intermediate results if either the `QualitativeResult` value is non-empty or the calculated row-number value is 1.

In short, this can be done with the following code:

```
WITH CTE_Unfiltered AS (
    SELECT
        ...original select items...
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY b.NotrId
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.QualitativeResult > '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ) AS RowNum

    FROM ...original table references...
)
SELECT ...
FROM CTE_Unfiltered
WHERE (Performance > '' OR RowNum = 1)
ORDER BY PN
```

As suggested in Thorsten Kettner's comments above, you can simplify your joins to just:

```
    FROM dbo.Results AS a
    JOIN dbo.NotrResult AS b
        ON a.NotrResultId = b.Id
    JOIN dbo.vNOTR AS c
        ON b.NotrId = c.NotrId
        AND c.DateCompleted IS NOT NULL
    JOIN dbo.Parameter AS d
        ON a.ParameterId = d.Id
```

The complete query would then become

```
WITH CTE_Unfiltered AS (
    SELECT
        b.NotrId AS NOTR
        ,c.DateCompleted AS Month
        ,c.ClientName AS Client
        ,c.SupplierName AS Supplier
        ,c.FacilityName AS Facility
        ,d.ParameterNumber AS PN
        ,d.Name AS [Parameter Name]
        ,a.QualitativeResult AS Performance
        ,a.Passed
        ,a.ParameterId
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY b.NotrId
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.QualitativeResult > '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM dbo.Results AS a
    JOIN dbo.NotrResult AS b
        ON a.NotrResultId = b.Id
    JOIN dbo.vNOTR AS c
        ON b.NotrId = c.NotrId
        AND c.DateCompleted IS NOT NULL
    JOIN dbo.Parameter AS d
        ON a.ParameterId = d.Id
    WHERE c.ClientName LIKE ('Sb')
    AND d.ParameterNumber IN('5006')
    AND c.ProductLineName LIKE ('%12%')
    AND c.ProductLineName NOT LIKE ('%Lid%')
    AND c.Qualification = ''
)
SELECT DISTINCT -- This DISTINCT is only needed because source data contains duplicates
    NOTR
    ,Month
    ,Client
    ,Supplier
    ,Facility
    ,PN
    ,[Parameter Name]
    ,Performance
    ,Passed
    ,ParameterId
FROM CTE_Unfiltered
WHERE (Performance > '' OR RowNum = 1)
ORDER BY PN
```

If the duplicate rows from the source data can be eliminated in advance, the `DISTINCT` can be removed from the final select.

Results:

| NOTR | Month | Client | Supplier | Facility | PN | Parameter Name | Performance | Passed | ParameterId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-14 13:30:00.000 | Sb | Pl | St | 5006 | 45t |  | 1 | cd0eeefc-a2f9-447c-a9b6-4931c83d8eac |
| 2 | 2021-12-14 13:35:00.000 | Sb | Pl | Dt | 5006 | 45t | 1/15 | 0 | cd0eeefc-a2f9-447c-a9b6-4931c83d8eac |
| 3 | 2021-12-15 10:10:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Fb | 5006 | 45t | 6/15 | 0 | ba8ddba0-71b0-4b7e-9b40-cac20439ef96 |
| 4 | 2021-12-14 13:45:00.000 | Sb | Dc | Ds | 5006 | 45t | 1/15 | 0 | ba8ddba0-71b0-4b7e-9b40-cac20439ef96 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SgWGGwBK) for a demo -  without duplicate source data, no `DISTINCT`, and with simplified joins.

Answer (score 0):

Although your `FROM` clause starts with `FROM dbo.Results`, it seems to me that it is actually mainly vNOTRs that you want to select and that you only want to join certain "best" results to them.

The following query does exactly that: It joins one result row per requested parameter to the vNOTR row. The "best" result is considered the one with the greatest qualitative result. SQL Server lacks the `NULLS FIRST/LAST` option in the `ORDER BY` clause, but `ORDER BY something DESC` places NULLs at the end, so we are fine without having to add a `CASE` expression for this. If it is empty strings you are dealing with, they come right next to the nulls, so we are equally fine here and will prefer any other value.

The query may not be the exact query that you are looking for, but hopefully gets you on the right track, so you can adjust it according to your needs.

```
SELECT
  vn.notrid AS notr,
  vn.datecompleted AS month,
  vn.clientname AS client,
  vn.suppliername AS supplier,
  vn.facilityname AS facility,
  res.pn,
  res.parameter_name,
  res.performance,
  res.Passed,
  res.ParameterId
FROM dbo.vnotr vn
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
    r.qualitativeresult AS performance,
    r.passed,
    r.parameterid,
    p.parameternumber AS pn,
    p.name AS parameter_name
  FROM dbo.notrresult nr
  JOIN dbo.results r ON r.notrresultid = nr.id
  JOIN dbo.parameter p ON p.id = r.parameterid AND p.parameternumber = '5006'
  WHERE nr.notrid = vn.notrid
  ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY r.qualitativeresult DESC)
) res
WHERE vn.ClientName = 'Sb'
  AND vn.ProductLineName LIKE '%12%'
  AND vn.ProductLineName NOT LIKE '%Lid%'
  AND vn.Qualification = ''
  AND vn.DateCompleted IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY pn, notr;
```